# How to share data in between two controllers using angular JS?

Tags: javascript, json, html, node.js, angularjs-scope

I am new to angular JS and Javascript. I am working on a angularJS project and In project i am using several modules like Secreport -> secreportpage -> secchart.

I passed data from mainCtrl to secreportCtrl through service.

```
StorageService.fetchGraphicalConfig(query.rpt, query.location)
    .success(function(graphconf) {
            $scope.error = null;
            $scope.graphconf = graphconf;
            $scope.clickFunction = function() {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('update_parent_controller',$scope.graphconf);
            };
        }).error(function(error) {
            $scope.error = error;
            $scope.graphconf = null;
        });
    }
```

After that i would like to share that same data to secchartctrl in secchart module.
 so, I used $broadcast,$on in secchartctrl

```
 $scope.$on('update_parent_controller', function (event,graphconf) {
        $scope.graphconf = graphconf;
    });
```

// when i debug and move cursor on graphconf  in secchartctrl it is showing undefined.

Kindly give a solution for that.
 Thank you in advance.

Comment: event propagation works only in the controllers which are currently exist. Can you post a plunker example to describe your problem